# How to affix a 3/4" keyed bore wheel/pulley to 5/8" D-profile shaft?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, mechanical, pulleys, wheels

How do I affix a [1.5-inch-thick wheel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AGZ6I8M) with a 0.75-inch keyed bore (or pulley) to my [motor's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0773VDXVZ) 1.25-inch-long x 5/8" diameter D-profile shaft (both pictured)"?

[image: motor and wheel]

Comment: some type of an adapter might work ... you should really replace one of those components, so that the two match

Comment: Say they were both D-profile, but the wheel was still wider than the shaft was long. How to solve?